# Matlab .txt file read error

Tags: matlab, synchronization, pid-controller

I'm using Matlab as a PI (proportional integral) controller. I'm trying to control a "virtual robot" agent via `.txt` files. The simulated agent writes errors in a `.txt` file. I run it through Matlab and set speed via a second `.txt` file, which the agent reads, all in realtime.

The problem is that sometimes Matlab tries to read the error file while the agent is using it (at least that's what I think is happening) and I get this error message:

```
??? Error using ==>
rfinputs>LocalTimeRespCheck at 421
Final time must be a positive
number.

Error in ==> PI_REG at 42
[v,t]=lsim(pid_d,E,t);
```

Is there a way to avoid it and have it synchronized perfect every time? Here is the code I'm using (`E.txt` is the error file, `V.txt` is the speed file):

```
clc, clear all, close all

Kp=1.3;                         
Ki=0.32;                       
Kd=0;                           
Ts=0.008;                       

pid_c = tf([Kd Kp Ki],[1 0]);   
pid_d = c2d(pid_c,Ts);          

fid=fopen('E.txt');
r=textscan(fid,'%f','\r\r');
fclose(fid);
E=r{1};

while length(E)<2464

s = dir('C:\Robot_1\E.txt');

if s.bytes == 0
pause(0.003)

else
fid=fopen('E.txt');
r=textscan(fid,'%f','\r\r');
fclose(fid);

E=r{1};                         %E is error in mm

t=[0:Ts:(length(E)-1)*Ts];

[v,t]=lsim(pid_d,E,t);

v;

V=v(length(E))                  %V is speed in mm/s

fid=fopen('V.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'%V6.4f\n',V);      
fclose(fid);

end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using text files to establish comm between robot and matlab?

Your question is not correctly stated as it does not say "where" is the robot: is it a remote mcu, or some code running in your own/another pc?

In the first case, i strongly recommend using a serial interface.

in the second case, use a socket(more robust/flexible and plenty of code for it) or something like pipes (no idea how to do it cleanly in matlab).
Using files for communication is simply a bad practice.

Comment: Its virtual robot, i should have mention that, fanucs roboguide

Comment: If possible, try to use sockets then